# What is wrong with my recursion in C?

Tags: c, function, recursion, combinations

I have written a recursive function for my homework to do the following calculation:

For the imput:
`1 2 3 4`

It should do this:
`((1*3)+2) + ((1*4)+3) = 13`, thats less than, `((2*4)+3) + ((1*4)+2) = 17`,  so it returns 13.
In letters it should do this calculation: `((A*C)+B) + ((A*D)+C)` and compare it with the other options, in this case there are 2 options: `((B*D)+C) + ((A*D)+C)`.

In few words. The numbers indicate the number of "screws" on each end of a segment. The segment is always formed by 2 numbers. Segment A {1 2}, B {2 3}, C {3 4}.

The task is to join all the N segments. I must find the "cheapest" way to do it. Every time I join two segments, (A and B for example), I do this:

"bottom screws"of A (1 - the first number)  * "top screws"of B (3 - the third number) + "joining screws" (2 - that is the number between).

I have to join them in order, it always must end in order ABCD. But I can choose where to start from. I can join A to B and then AB to C, or i can join B to C and then A to BC. Basically in one of the cases the "cost" will be the lowest and thats the value to return.

For now I have done this, but I got confused:

The `*help` is a intercalculation array which i use to store the new values gotten in the recursion.

```
int *help;
```

The `*mezi` is a dynamically alocated array defined as:

```
int *mezi;
```

And inside it looks like `{0,4,1,2,3,4,-1}`.

```
mezi[0] = here is stored the total prize in the recursion.

mezi[1] = here is stored the number of values in the array, 4 for 4 values (3 segments).

mezi[n+2] = the last number (-1), its just an identifier to find out the number of values.
```

Here's my code:

```
int findmin(int *mezi, int *pomocny)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int prize, prizemin, mini, minih;

    for (i=3;i<mezi[1];i++) {

        prize = mezi[i-1] * mezi[i+1] + mezi[i];
        if (i==3) { mini = i; minih = prize; }

        if (prize < minih) { mini = i; minih = prize; }

        if (mezi[1] > 3){

            k=2;
            for (j=2;j<mezi[1];j++) {
                if (j != mini) help[k] = mezi[j];
                k++;
            }
            help[1] = (mezi[1]-1);
        }
        help[0] += prize;

        findmin(help,help);
    }
    prizemin = help[0];

    return prizemin;
}
```

Im kinda of a novice, I started using C not long ago and the recursive functions cofuse me a lot. I would reallz appretiate help. Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your base case?

Comment: Do you mean my main condition thate terminates the recursion? If so it shoud be the line:  
if (mezi[1] > 3){

Comment: But inside that `if` you don't terminate the recursion..

Comment: If you have not looked into your system's debugger now is a good time. Nothing like watching the code do something you did not plan on to help you understand what is going wrong and hopefully how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your program logic.

```
int findmin(int *mezi, int *pomocny)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int prize, prizemin, mini, minih;

    for (i=3;i<mezi[1];i++) 
    {
        prize = mezi[i-1] * mezi[i+1] + mezi[i];
        if (i==3) { mini = i; minih = prize; } //This is a redundant test and 
        //initialization. i == 3 is true only in the first run of the loop. These
        //initialization should be done in the loop itself

        if (prize < minih) { mini = i; minih = prize; }

        if (mezi[1] > 3){  //This is also redundant as mezi[3] is always greater than 3 
        // otherwise the loop wont run as you check for this in your test expression

            k=2;
            for (j=2;j<mezi[1];j++) {
                if (j != mini) help[k] = mezi[j];
                k++;
            }
            help[1] = (mezi[1]-1);
        }
        help[0] += prize;

        //The only base case test you have is mezi[1]<3 which you should make sure is 
        // present in your data set

        findmin(help,help);
    }
    prizemin = help[0];

    return prizemin;
}
```